# Removing objects from array within range of each other

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an Array of enemy objects, I want to check if there x and y position are within 10 pixels of each other and if they are remove them. My method seems to be removing everything i'm not sure what is wrong.

```
function checkEnemyPos()
{
    for (var i =0; i < enemys.length; i ++)
    {
        for (var j =0,len = enemys.length; j <len; j ++)
        {
            var xRange = Math.abs(enemys[j].x - enemys[i].x);
            var yRange = Math.abs(enemys[j].y - enemys[i].y);


            if (xRange < 10 && yRange < 10)
            {
                enemys.splice(j, 1);
                j--;
                len--;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result as well.

Comment: It's because your for loop is such that you compare each enemy to itself as well as all the other enemies.

Comment: btw, the start of the second loop check the first element of first loop. the result is, you remove **all** items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust the looping, the outer loop from zero to length -1 and the inner loop from `i + 1` to the length of the array.

> Example for `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
>
> ```
>    0  1  2  3  4  5  i
> 1  x                       x = check
> 2  x  x
> 3  x  x  x
> 4  x  x  x  x
> 5  x  x  x  x  x
> 6  x  x  x  x  x  x
> j
> ```

```
function checkEnemyPos() {
    for (var i = 0; i < enemys.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < enemys.length; j++) {
            var xRange = Math.abs(enemys[j].x - enemys[i].x);
            var yRange = Math.abs(enemys[j].y - enemys[i].y);

            if (xRange < 10 && yRange < 10) {
                enemys.splice(j, 1);
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from zero to length - 2, and from i + 1 to length - 1 is what you have coded, which is correct.  The key part being `j = i + 1`, the rest is kind of irrelevant, because if `i == enemys.length - 1`, j will be outside its loop range.